# How to parse JSON in Java using a high performance parser?

Tags: java, json

My input is an array with approx. 2,000 elements received every second, sometimes several times per second. Every element of the array has 3 Big Decimals.

Jackson (com.fasterxml) is the slowest part of otherwise sub-millisecond app and takes 15 milliseconds (avg). The slow function is objectMapper.readValue(text, MyDto.class);

When using a custom JSON parsing algorithm based on substring, it takes microseconds. With ObjectMapper it's 15 milliseconds.

Parsing JSON via substring is a bad practice because the code is verbose and prone to bugs.

What would you use for JSON parsing? The requirement is a very fast algorithm.

https://github.com/ngs-doo/dsl-json I found DSL json, but don't know hot to make it parse a String with JSON into my DTO. I haven't found a simple fast algorithm to parse JSON from String into a DTO.

EDIT: The input to be parsed is at:

```
https://pastebin.com/831YtBdq
```

Code:

```
public class BitstampOrderBook {
    private long timestamp;
    private List<List<BigDecimal>> bids;
    private List<List<BigDecimal>> asks;

    public BitstampOrderBook() {

    }

    public BitstampOrderBook(long timestamp, List<List<BigDecimal>> bids, List<List<BigDecimal>> asks) {
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
        this.bids = bids;
        this.asks = asks;
    }

    public long getTimestamp() {
        return timestamp;
    }

    public List<List<BigDecimal>> getBids() {
        return bids;
    }

    public List<List<BigDecimal>> getAsks() {
        return asks;
    }
}

public class BitstampOrder {
    private BigDecimal price;

    private BigDecimal amount;

    private String datetime;

    private int id;

    @SerializedName("order_type")
    private int orderType;

    public BigDecimal getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(BigDecimal price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public BigDecimal getAmount() {
        return amount;
    }

    public void setAmount(BigDecimal amount) {
        this.amount = amount;
    }

    public String getDatetime() {
        return datetime;
    }

    public void setDatetime(String datetime) {
        this.datetime = datetime;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getOrderType() {
        return orderType;
    }

    public void setOrderType(int orderType) {
        this.orderType = orderType;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "BitStampOrder{" +
                "price=" + price +
                ", amount=" + amount +
                ", datetime='" + datetime + '\'' +
                ", id='" + id + '\'' +
                ", orderType='" + orderType + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Main:

```
BitstampOrderBook orderBook = objectMapper.readValue(jsonString, BitstampOrderBook.class);
```

JProfiler (Jackson):

```
https://i.imgur.com/mjdbDQe.png
```

EDIT 2:

JProfiler (Gson):

```
https://i.imgur.com/WcHVhhd.png
```

As can be seen from JProfiler, Gson is several times faster than Jackson. What would be even faster than Gson?

Comment: It might be worth to show the code you use for Jackson benchmarking, micros vs millis performance improvement compared to naive manual parsing sounds odd.

Comment: [4. **Questions asking us to recommend or find a** book, tool, **software library**, tutorial or other off-site resource **are off-topic for Stack Overflow**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: @AllenHacks try to create a reader `objectMapper.reader(MyDto.class);` beforehand.

Comment: @khachik I've tried to create the reader as a private property. It does not shave any millisecond at run time. The profiler shows ObjectMapper.readValue() boils down to com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize inside of which is NumberDeserializers$BigDecimalDeserializer.deserialize and that is the slowest part of Jackson.

Comment: give [Moshi](https://github.com/square/moshi) a try, ppl recommend it exactly for performance and low memory footprints

Comment: @VladimirL. https://i.imgur.com/qTDrSUH.png this is just 658 invocations and it already takes 4,786ms. The exact same input and the same DTO in over 2000 invocations compounds to around 500ms with Gson.  So Moshi is the slowest of the trio. Jackson does better, Gson does best. I don't know how to use "DSL Json" and I think it's gonna beat Gson.

Comment: @AllenHacks Ditching of java.math.BigDecimal is a best thing what you can do to save your security and performance. Have you ever tried to run `(new java.math.BigDecimal("1000000000e1000000000")).add(new java.math.BigDecimal(1));` ? Try it, and see what it will happen if anybody send you a such kind of value through JSON.

Comment: @AllenHacks do not use JProfiler for benchmarking... use JMH instead which can run some profilers like perf, gc, etc. But if you switch to Scala and will use sbt-jmh plugin you will got ability to profile benchmarks properly with the best profilers like JFR or AsyncProfiler

Comment: @Andriy Double and Float cannot represent floating point numbers exactly, hence BigDecimal is the only option. Security: An attacker can exhaust memory with a specially crafted malicious Json payload! The data is read from an Exchange and it is wss (secure web socket).

Comment: ...funny ...there was a time where Jackson was among the fastest ...but I guess adding features over features has now slowed it down. Seriously though, for this kind of stuff, just look at benchmarks: https://github.com/fabienrenaud/java-json-benchmark

Comment: Again, according to benchmarks, Jackson still appears to be one of the faster ones, and faster than Gson. Perhaps it's specific to your use case or a usage issue.

Comment: Everybody knows the benchmarks measure something else than my test case from the original post. In that test case, Jackson does horribly! Gson performs several times faster there.

Comment: @AllenHacks - Nothing can represent real numbers exactly.  (Decimal) floating point is just another inexact representation.  But if you are talking about financial values, then `long` or `integer` are more efficient *exact* representations when suitably scaled.

Answer (score 0):

1. Do not use strings as input, parse buffered bytes that you read from the wire or disks immediately instead.
2. Do not bind to BigDecimal, use double primitive instead + efficient formatter according to your rules if you will need to serialize its value back to JSON with the same precision.
3. Use 2-field class for your inner arrays of price/amount pairs.
4. Switch to Scala and use [jsoniter-scala](https://github.com/plokhotnyuk/jsoniter-scala) (DECLAIMER: I'm a contributor to this amazing library).

Done all these steps and you will get more than 400Mb per second speed when parsing of your samples in one thread.

See results of `GeoJSONReading` which parses [mostly the same kind of JSON (arrays of 2-value sub-arrays of numbers)](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plokhotnyuk/jsoniter-scala/master/jsoniter-scala-benchmark/src/main/resources/com/github/plokhotnyuk/jsoniter_scala/macros/che.geo.json) [here](http://jmh.morethan.io/?source=https://plokhotnyuk.github.io/jsoniter-scala/oraclejdk-13.json).

Comment: 1. I use OkHttp, Pusher, and SignalR as 3 web socket adapters. OkHtttp and Pusher send me String. They don't let me grab buffered streams. How would you do it?

Comment: 2. Double and Float cannot represent floating point numbers exactly. I have to use BigDecimal

Comment: 3. I have tried and evaluated the List vs Array. It doesn't make any performance difference. Arrays should be theoretically faster.

Comment: 4. I've tried Jsoniter (java) http://jsoniter.com and unlike the vendor's synthetic benchmark the real-world benchmark with the above JSON and POJOs doesn't make jsoniter perform so well. It's approximately as slow as jackson. I hoped jsoniter would beat Gson, but no, jsoniter is several times slower when tested with JProfiler. I've executed the test twice to confirm and came up with the approximately same numbers. I'ts unbelivable how slow jsoniter was compared to gson. I've tried only the API that is Gson compatibility mode.

Comment: 1. Use efficient HTTP clients instead that can provide access to bytes through arrays or input streams. 2. You cannot represent any floating point numbers exactly with BigDecimal until you have used unlimited math context. But using it is a great security hole. 3. If you cannot spot difference in performance of array or list than revise your benchmarking tools or their usage. 4. Jsoniter-scala does not  depend on Jsoniter (Java) - it ended up to implement whole parsing and serializing from the scratch. So you definitely need to try it if you really looking for high-performant JSON parser.

Comment: @AllenHacks BTW, OkHttp has an API to get an array of bytes or InputStream of the received response body: https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/master/okhttp/src/main/java/okhttp3/ResponseBody.java

Comment: @AndriyPlokhotnykuk Data comes via WebSocket. With OkHTTP3 the WebSocketListener class has two different onMessage. One accepts String the other ByteStream. I've tested with 10 different web socket sources and every time OkHTTP calls the onMessage that accepts String. It never calls the ByteStream one. I believe it would call it if the other end would send binary data instead of String. Regarding BigDecimal, I do not understand what point you are trying to make. 10 / 3 gives the exact result when it's BigDecimal. 1.33 can be stored exactly when it's BigDecimal. Double/float give rounding error

Comment: @AndriyPlokhotnykuk regarding parsing, I've briefly studied different parser algorithms. LL, LR, Pratt, and a few other. They typically transform the input into a parse tree. Then, they take data from the parse tree and assign them to DTO. It's slower than approaches that don't use a parse tree. For example, JSON can be transformed into DTO using a tailor made algorithm for that specific JSON. It's faster than Jsoniter-scala. Regarding array vs List in Java I haven't seen any measurable difference. I've used JProfiler for that. The difference was so small it didn't affect the result.